# How ball tree classification algorithm works?

Tags: clustering

Good afternoon!

My question is very simple. I searched on the web without finding an answer.

I'm wanting to understand how **the ball tree algorithm works** ( i prefer step by step in a simple example ).

I don't know if my question meets the StackExchange rules. However, I wish you could help!

Thank you a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: Check this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1_WCdUAtyE

Comment: or this post: https://towardsdatascience.com/tree-algorithms-explained-ball-tree-algorithm-vs-kd-tree-vs-brute-force-9746debcd940

Comment: I had found some equations here : https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume7/liu06a/liu06a.pdf . However i think the author didn't clarify how to compute pivots of the two created balls !